# Is it possible to have 2 keyboards and two mice operate independently on the the same desktop screen?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, input

where one user operates a mouse/keyboard remotely?

I'm open to Windows or Ubuntu....

I've tried online services like https://www.use-together.com/ and we cannot type at the same time, it goes in a sequence. We'd like to be able to type at the exact same time.

I want to see two pointers at once.

Any suggestions welcome, thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, In Windows, Mac and Ubuntu, there is no default support for having two mouse pointers on the screen. Your best bet is to mess with the core operating system to obtain this. Maybe some third party apps allow you to do so. But I'm curious where would you need it?

We use collaborative working on number of places. If you want to type on a document at the same time, I suggest you Google Drive that helps to work collobratively on its applications. You can add as many collaborators as you want and all of them would be working just fine.

Just visit [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com) and sign in with your google account.

```
1) Create a New Document (Google Doc) or Spreadsheet (Google Sheet)
2) Share the document with the person you want to remotely work with.
3) Start working.
```

There are many other apps (Google and many others) that support online collaboration and allows multiple users to connect to a single app.